# how to parse android sqlite query to java

Tags: sql, android-sqlite, sql-parser

I have a lot of android sqlite queries fed as input. I have to parse those to java, search from vectors and return the result. How can I handle this ???

Are there any plugins like JSqlParser, SQL parser, JoSQL for android sqlite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would give JSqlParser a try. Its the one I am most familiar with. Its parser is not limited to one specific dbms so if you are processing "normal" sqls it should work.